# Query to return

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query which would return results  in line with the following.. For three tables, customers, products and order history, I want to find the latest order for each product for each customer.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the **table structures** (what columns with what datatypes do you have), and if possible some sample data for each table, and the expected output. And it also helps to specify ***what concrete database*** this is for.... add a relevant tag: `mysql`,  `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server` - they all use **SQL** as their query language - but there are differences between them

Comment: Hi, Sorry for lack of detail I'm fairly new to Sql.  It's SQL Server.  Tables Customer: Cust Id, FirstName, SurnameName, Company  Product: ProductId, ProductName, Cost  OrderHistory: OrderID, CustID, ProductID, OrderDate

Comment: ...we still need the table schema or we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

*The latest order for each product for each customer* - you can achieve this by using a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and partitioning your data by those *for each* criteria.

So try something like this (just guessing table and column names, since you haven't provided anything to go on):

```
;WITH NewestData AS
(
    SELECT
        oh.OrderDate,
        c.CustomerName, 
        p.ProductName,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.CustomerID, oh.ProductID
                                    ORDER BY oh.OrderDate DESC)
    FROM
        dbo.OrderHistory oh
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Customer c ON oh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Product p ON oh.ProductID = p.ProductID
)
SELECT
   OrderDate, CustomerName, ProductName
FROM       
   NewestData
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
```

OK, explanation time:

- the CTE (Common Table Expression) basically joins the three tables (guessing what the table and column names are, and how they are connected) and selects some of the columns from those tables (you could add more columns, if you need them, of course!)
- the `RowNum` is a consecutive number, starting at 1, for each "partition" of data; the `PARTITION BY` clause expresses that for each combination of a `(CustomerID, ProductID)`, you want to have a "partition" which gets numbered (1, 2, 3, 4,.....) based on the `ORDER BY` clause - here, it gets number with `1` for the most recent order for that partition (for that customer+product).

So in the end, all you need to do, is select from that CTE, and select those rows only that have `RowNum = 1` - those are the *most recent* orders for each "partition" of `(CustomerID, ProductID)` in your order history table.

This works from SQL Server **2005** on and newer versions - it is *not* supported in 2000 .....

Comment: Marc_s, Many thanks for your help, especially as I have was able to give such little detail, I will try it in work on Monday and let you know how I get on.  Regards Des.